# How can I make a node.js server accessible to others on my network?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is a pretty straightforward question. Normally in a node app, you put `http.listen('1300', '127.0.0.1);`. Is there some way to do this so that other computer on my network can access the server?

I have tried this:

```
http.listen('1300', '192.168.0.1);
```

As well as this:

```
http.listen('1300', [My IP address])
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved by using this:

```
http.listen('1300');
```

And I access it by typing `[hostname(in this case, my computers name)]:1300` into the URL bar. Hope this helps anyone who is having similar issues!

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback

you should omit the host parameter.

the practice to add the address is just to increase security (limiting the allowed hosts to your machine)